# Unexpected result from a division

Tags: c, division

I tried to implement the following calculation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

    float sum = 0;
    int c = -4;
    float x1 = 136.67;
    float x2 = 2.38;

    sum = c / (pow(abs(x1 - x2), 2));
    printf("%f %f %f",sum,x1,x2);

    return 0;
}
```

But the value of `sum` after the execution turns out to be -4. What is wrong?

Comment: I ran this code on Visual Studio 2012. The value of sum is -.000221805691 for me.

Comment: http://codepad.org/b6kw6o2X

Comment: I compiled the code with GCC.

Comment: How is this possible?

Comment: It seems to be a problem in the casting from `float` to `int` in the `abs()` function. When I break it in chunks, it works.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: The problem is: (a) `abs` operates on `int`s, not on floating-point; (b) `abs` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`, which is not `#include`d, and (c) the program uses `abs` rather than the correct function `fabs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abs` expects an integer, and you are providing a `float`. It should work if you apply an explicit type cast:

```
sum = c / (pow(abs((int)(x1 - x2)), 2));
```

Comment: Casting the argument isn't the solution. It's still calling the `abs` function, which takes an `int` argument. With the required `#include <stdlib.h>`, the conversion would be done implicitly -- and would still yield an incorrect result. The OP almost certainly wants to use the `fabs` function. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23525749/827263).

Answer (score 2):

`abs` is declared in `<stdlib.h>`. It takes an `int` argument and returns an `int` result.

The missing `#include <stdlib.h>` is likely to cause problems as well. You're calling `abs` with a floating-point argument; without a visible declaration, the compiler will probably assume that it takes a `double` argument, resulting in incorrect code. (That's under C90 rules; under C99 rules, the call is a constraint violation, requiring a compile-time diagnostic.)

You want the `fabs` function defined in `<math.h>`.